# Replace data in json file with a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a json file in the following format

```
"rawDataBody":
    {
        "data": [
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "unit": "",
            "format": "integer",
            "key": "Test"
           }
        ],
        "dataBlock": [
        [7, 1730569828, 3490, 1608636960, 30.62, 1003.82, 44.14, 683806.38, 2, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1730563432, 3545, 1608636960, 29.89, 1003.52, 39.25, 557582.38, 2, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1730579048, 3571, 1608636960, 29.79, 1003.45, 41.07, 494566.53, 2, 1, 0, 0],
        [2, 1730568292, 3595, 1608636960, 29.62, 1003.40, 42.72, 546424.75, 2, 1, 0, 0],
```

I want to replace the data in the dataBlock with my dataframe and extract the whole in json file

```
5.0,1730566755.0,22.11,1608636969.0,33.42,1003.5,39.78,60591.71,9.0,1.0,0.0,0.0
6.0,1730551139.0,22.14,1608636969.0,33.27,1003.64,38.77,77906.27,9.0,1.0,0.0,0.0
6.0,1730551139.0,22.14,1608636969.0,33.27,1003.64,38.77,77906.27,9.0,1.0,0.0,0.0
5.0,1730566755.0,42.11,1608636969.0,33.42,1003.5,39.78,60591.71,9.0,1.0,0.0,0.0
```

The code i have tried is. I dont know why this is not working.can someone help me

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    jsonData = json.load(file)
    dfFinalResult = dfFinalResult.values.tolist()
    for item in jsonData['rawDataBody']['dataBlock']:
        item = dfFinalResult
    with open('newjsonfile.txt', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(jsonData, file)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `jsonData['rawDataBody']['dataBlock'] = dfFinalResult`?

Comment: I mean to replace the dataBlock values with the dffinalResult (dataFrame) and extract the new replace json file

Comment: So, what happened when you tried what I suggested?

Comment: It works but how do i extract the new jsonData as a json file.My code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be saying that my suggestion worked.

Here is what I think you should have:

```py
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    jsonData = json.load(file)

dfFinalResult = dfFinalResult.values.tolist()
jsonData['rawDataBody']['dataBlock'] = dfFinalResult

with open('newjsonfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(jsonData, file)
```